# sympy atan not returning exact value

Tags: python, math, sympy, trigonometry

The following input, when run through `sympy`

```
atan(2+sqrt(3))
```

returns

```
1.30899693899575
```

instead of

```
5π/12
```

Why is that?

Comment: In fact, it does: `sympy.atan(2+sympy.sqrt(3)).evalf()==(5*sympy.pi/12).evalf()` is `True`.

Comment: Yes, it evaluates the value to true but isn't in the list of special values that gets returned in exact form. (Assuming such a list exists)

Comment: Then your question is incorrectly asked: you are not looking for an exact value, but for a special-form value. The answer would be: presumably, 5π/12 is not considered special enough.

Comment: what's wrong with the result? `5π/12 ≈ 1.3089969389957471826927680763665`. Normal arithmetic doesn't return a symbol result

Comment: @phuclv SymPy _is_ a symbolic system.

Comment: @DYZ but the expression in the question is not related to sympy

Comment: @phuclv But did you read the question title?

Comment: @DYZ but did you see `atan(2+sqrt(3))`? how does sympy apply to it? If anything, the question doesn't contain a [mcve]

Comment: @phuclv If you do `from sympy import *`, then `atan(2+sqrt(3))` becomes a legal SymPy expression. What are you arguing against? The question is unquestionably about SymPy.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `atan(2+sqrt(3))` returns `atan(2+sqrt(3))` for me, not `1.30899693899575`.

Comment: @wrzlprmft You've got to `.eval()` it.

Comment: @DYZ "sympy.atan(2+sympy.sqrt(3)).evalf()==(5*sympy.pi/12).evalf() is True" is beside the point, isn't it? The point of a symbolic system is to avoid numerical approximations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suspect that the result can be written in terms of pi you can try `nsimplify` with a hint of pi given as a constant.

```
>>> nsimplify(atan(sqrt(3) + 2), [pi])
5*pi/12
```

BTW, you can see what special values are recognized by any of the trig functions by looking at the source code for their `eval` methods.

Comment: I don't know how nsimplify works. Does it look for numerical approximations such as: result/hint = rational with not too big denominator? If so that's a little unsatisfying; it would be much better to have an exact result, since it's not hard to make up examples that could fool heuristics.